# Android Studio cannot resolve android... and java... namespaces

Tags: android, android-studio, symbols

I've searched to my wit's end and cannot find a solution to my issue so I now come to you for help.

In short, Android Studio  (0.2.10) can compile and run my project fine but the IDE itself cannot resolve most android and java namespaces.  This also means the syntax autocomplete doesn't work.

For instance:
import android.content.Intent;  (doesn't work)
import android.os.Bundle;  (doesn't work)
import android.view.View;  (doesn't work)
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction **(works!)**
import java.util.HashMap;  (doesn't work)
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;  **(works!)**
import com.myApplication.anything;  **(works!)**

Facts:

-I have verified that my local.properties is pointed at my SDK.

-I've done lots of Invalidate Cache/Restarts, Rebuilds, "gradlew clean", and "gradlew build"s

-I've pulled fresh code from our source control to a new location (which works correctly on my coworkers' Macs and PCs) - I use Win7 64bit.

-New projects I create locally do NOT have this issue - only this shared project.

If anyone has any insight they can share as to why this could be happening, I'd really appreciate it.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure your Project SDK is set correctly. To access this go right-click your project and choose `Open Module Settings`. Then go under `Project` to check the set `Project SDK`. If no SDK is configured you can add it under the `SDKs` heading.